# Erlang: is two stage init safe?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

When using gen_server, sometimes I need to do a "two stage init" or "detached init", which goes like this:

a) in the gen_server callback module's `init/1`, only part of the initialization is done

b) after that, a `self() ! init_stage2` is called

c) `init/1` returns `{ok, PartiallyInitializedState}`

d) at some point of future, the `handle_info/2` is called to process the `init_stage2` message sent in b), thus complete the initilization process.

My **main concern** is that, if a gen server `call` / `cast` / `info` is made between c) and d), is it possible for that request to be processed with the `PartiallyInitializedState`?

According to [10.8  Is the order of message reception guaranteed?](http://erlang.org/faq/academic.html), (quoted, below), this is possible, (if I understand it right), but I cannot produce a failure (a request between c) and d) is processed with the partially initilized state)

> Yes, but only within one process.
>
> If there is a live process and you send it message A and then message B, it's guaranteed that if message B arrived, message A arrived before it.
>
> On the other hand, imagine processes P, Q and R. P sends message A to Q, and then message B to R. There is no guarantee that A arrives before B. (Distributed Erlang would have a pretty tough time if this was required!)

Below is some code I used trying to get the call to be processed between c) and d), but of course failed, otherwise, I wouldn't be asking this question here. (use `test:start(20000)` to run, if you are interested)

```
%% file need_two_stage_init.erl
-module(need_two_stage_init).

-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/0]).

-export([init/1, terminate/2, code_change/3,
         handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2]).


start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, {}, []).


init({}) ->
    self() ! go_to_stage2,
    %% init into stage1
    {ok, stage1}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, Stage) ->
    {reply, Stage, Stage}.

%% upon receiving this directive, go to stage2,
%% in which the gen_server is fully functional
handle_info(go_to_stage2, stage1) ->
    {noreply, stage2}.

handle_cast(Request, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ignore.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.



%% file test.erl
-module(test).

-export([start/1]).

start(Amount) ->
    start_collector(Amount), %% report the result
    start_many_gens(Amount).

start_collector(Amount) ->
    spawn(fun() ->
                  register(collector, self()),
                  io:format("collector started, entering receive loop~n"),
                  loop(Amount)
          end).

loop(0) ->
    io:format("all terminated~n"),
    all_terminated;
loop(N) ->
    %% progress report
    case N rem 5000 == 0 of
        true -> io:format("remaining ~w~n", [N]);
        false -> ignore
    end,
    receive
        {not_ok, _} = Msg ->
            io:format("======= bad things happened: ~p~n", [Msg]),
            loop(N-1);
        {ok, _} ->
            loop(N-1)
    end.


start_one_gens() ->
    {ok, Pid} = need_two_stage_init:start_link(),
    case gen_server:call(Pid, any) of
        stage2 -> ignore;
        stage1 -> collector ! {not_ok, Pid}
    end,
    gen_server:stop(Pid),
    collector ! {ok, Pid}.


start_many_gens(Amount) ->
    lists:foreach(fun(_) ->
                          spawn(fun start_one_gens/0)
                  end, lists:seq(1, Amount)).
```

**Edit** Reading the above quoted documentation again, I think I did misunderstand it, *"If there is a live process and you send it message A and then message B, it's guaranteed that if message B arrived, message A arrived before it."* It didn't say who sent A, and who sent B, I guess it means that it doesn't matter, as long as they were sent to the same process, in which case, the two stage init practice is safe. Anyway, it would be nice if some Erlang/OTP guru can clarify this.

(off the topic, saying "Erlang/OTP" feels like those GNU guys forces you to say "GNU Linux" :-)

**Edit 2** Thanks to @Dogbert, the short version of this question can be stated in these two ways:

1) if a process send a message to itself, is this message guaranteed to reach the mailbox synchronously?

2) or, let A, B and P be three different processes, A send MsgA to P first, then B send MsgB to P, is it guaranteed that MsgA arrives before MsgB?

Answer (score 1):

In your case `gen_server:start_link/3` will not returns until your `need_two_stage_init:init/1` returns. So either `need_two_stage_init:start_link/0`. It means there is already `go_to_stage2` in your mailbox. So when you are not using registered name there is not anybody knowing your `Pid` except your process calling `gen_server:start_link/3` but it is hidden there until return anyway. So you are safe because nobody can `call`, `cast` or send you a message not knowing `Pid`.

BTW you can achieve similar effect returning `{ok, PartiallyInitializedState, 0}` and then handle `timeout` in `hanle_info/2`.

(off topic, there is history behind GNU in Linux when Linux was work of Linus and small community around him and GNU was already established huge project with lot of userspace applications so they have good reason to be mentioned in name of OS which consist lot of their work. Erlang is language and OTP is distribution of utilities and modules but its both work of the same group of people so they probably forgive you.)

ad 1) No, it is not guaranteed, it's a way how it is currently implemented and it is unlikely to change in foreseen future because it is simple and robust. When a process sends a message to a process in the same VM it copies message term to the separated heap/environment and then atomically appends a message to the linked list of a message box. I'm not sure if the message is copied if the process sends the message to itself. There is *shared heap* implementation which doesn't copy message but none of those details change the fact, that message is linked to the receiver's message box before the process continues its work.

ad 2) First of all, how you know B sends a message after A sends a message? Think about it. Then we could talk about MasgA and MsgB. No there is not guaranteed that MsgA arrives before MsgB especially if A, B, and P are each on different VM especially different computers. The only way to guarantee B sends the message MsgB after A sends MsgA is to send MsgC from A after A sends MsgA to the P but even if B sends MsgB to the P after receives MsgC, there is not guaranteed that the P receives MsgA before MsgB. So in scenario A sends MsgA to P and then MsgC to B and B receives MsgC and then sends MsgB to P you know MsgA was sent before MsgB but P still in rare circumstances could receive MsgB before MsgA when A, B, and P are on different computers connected by a network. It should never happen when A, B, and P are on same VM due way how message sending is implemented.

Comment: Is it not theoretically possible for the message sent by the process to itself in `init` to reach after `start_link` returns and another process sends it a message since message sending is asynchronous and messages from different processes to one process aren't guaranteed to reach in order?

Comment: @Dogbert: You have process A which starts process B which sends message P to the self. Then send message Q to the A which makes A finish `need_two_stage_init:start_link/0` and return `Pid`. Then process A or another process C which receives `Pid` as a message will send message R which you ask could arrive before P. Well, very unlikely because P was sent from B to B which is technically just inserting a pointer to linked list of its own mailbox. Synchronously. Before sending Q to A. So unlikely you can depend on it.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem highly unlikely like you described. I tried to search whether a message from a process to itself is guaranteed to reach instantly/synchronously or before another process sends another message but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Excellent point about MsgC, but in some cases (I really want to say in most cases, but I don't have proof :-) you don't need a MsgC to ensure MsgB was sent after MsgA, instead, you can rely on the evaluation order, take the code snippet in the question as an example, we know that if you do a gen call after `init` has returned, the `$gen_call` message will be sent after `go_to_stage2`, because `self() ! go_to_stage2` is evaluated first.

Comment: @NotanID: No, definitely not. How do you think this `init` is performed? How do you think `gen_server:init/3` knows your `need_two_stage_init:init/1` finished? Look how it is implemented. There is `MsgC` right there. No, there is not any other way to order `MsgA` and `MsgB` sent from two different processes `A` and `B` than send synchronization `MsgC` message. It is how Erlang work. `gen_server:init/3` is performed in one process and `need_two_stage_init:init/1` in other one. There is not another way around than send the message in Erlang and it is exactly how it is done. See `proc_lib`.

Comment: from a implementation view, you are right, in most cases, message passing is the only sane way for two processes to communicate. but my point is, when you are reasoning about/writing programs, you don't have to think about implementation, (implementation can always change, but specification don't), I know MsgA was sent (not necessarily received) before MsgB because I know that the expression that sends MsgA gets evaluated before the one sends MsgB, that's how I wrote the code.

Comment: @NotanID: I don't think it is a good way to think about it. In Erlang, you can't order two things in two separate processes any other way than sending a message. That's the rule. It helps you design your code and it helps you reason about it and it helps understand how other people's code was written including OTP. Yes, there is `ets` (but it could be implemented using processes and messages and API reflects it) and you can make dirty stuff in NIF but then it is your fault if it would not work well.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to receive a message between the 2 steps, even if it is unlikely, specially if the server is not registered (because there is few chance that another process uses the pid of the server) but with a registered process it is possible for example when a supervisor restart a server while some other part of the application. To show it in action I wrote a small example which fails systematically (when launched as test(bad)).

To achieve it I have inserted a sleep 100ms in the init function. It gives time for another process to sen a message to the server under initialization and may simulate a long init function.

I use a second process is spawn previously and send a message to the server every 10ms. The message uses the registered name so I don't need to know the pid, it is sent in a catch block, because some of the first message emission will fail since the server is not registered yet.

```
-module(twosteps).

-behaviour(gen_server).

%% export interfaces
-export([start_link/0,test/1,stop/0,badguy/0]).

%% export callbacks
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

%% INTERFACES %%

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

stop() ->
    gen_server:stop(?MODULE).

test(good) ->
    start_link(),
    ?MODULE ! this_will_work,
    stop();
test(bad) ->
    Pid = spawn(?MODULE,badguy,[]),
    start_link(),
    stop(),
    Pid ! stop.


%% CALLBACKS %%

init(_) ->
    timer:sleep(100),
    self() ! finish_init,
    {ok, first_step}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    {reply, {error, unknown_call}, State}.

handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(finish_init, first_step) ->
    io:format("Init OK~n"),
    {noreply, init_done};
handle_info(finish_init, too_late) ->
    io:format("iznogoud~n"),
    {noreply, too_late};
handle_info(_Info, first_step) ->
    io:format("Init KO, state is first_step~n"),
    {noreply, too_late};
handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    io:format("State is ~p~n",[State]),
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

%% LOCAL FUNCTIONS %%

badguy() ->
    catch (?MODULE ! this_will_fail),
    receive
        stop -> ok
    after 10 ->
        badguy()
    end.
```

in action:

```
1> c(twosteps).
{ok,twosteps}
2> twosteps:test(good).
Init OK
State is init_done
ok
3> twosteps:test(bad). 
Init KO, state is first_step
State is too_late
State is too_late
State is too_late
State is too_late
State is too_late
iznogoud
State is too_late
State is too_late
stop
4>
```

Comment: The reused pid and registered name indeed can make two step init fail, but that's not the core of this question, see _Edit 2_.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean in 1) in your example, the server will finish the init, return to the "otp code" and then will be called on info callback., but for item 2) there is no guarantee.

Comment: In 1), I mean, if sending a message to the process itself is done synchronously, then the two stage init is safe to use, because all calls are made after the `init/1` has returned, which means `self() ! go_to_stage2` has been evaluated, and because the assumption (a message to the process itself is done synchronously), the `go_to_stage2` would already be in the mailbox before any gen call

Comment: It feels bad when you have to dig into the implementation instead of documentation to understand something.

Comment: @NotanID Sending to the process sync or async has no bearing, it is the same `!` after all. The only important thing is when it occurs. The way @Pascal shows here is the "standard" way of splitting a long init into a short first phase and a longer second phase. It is not 100% safe, as shown here, but you really have to try to break it, again as shown here. Basically the process has to be registered and you continually send to that name.

Comment: @NotanID The other "standard" way it include a `0` timeout in the `{init,Ret,0}` which will make the top-loop generate a call to `handle_info` with the argument `timeout`. The sending yourself a message way is better.

Comment: @NotanID why do you need to dig into the implementation?

Comment: @NotanId it is not necessary to dig into the code, except if you want to understand and learn what are the underlying problems which exist in a multi-core, multi-node,  multi-computer application. The documentation says it all, the messages from a process A to a process B are received in the same order they were sent (with some messages lost eventually), in all other cases, there is no guarantee about the reception order.

Comment: So the only way this can fail is to use a registered name. Using a registry or sending directly to pids guarantee that you can safely send to self because you will send to self before any other code knows about you pid, because start_link will only return after you send to self. True ?

Comment: oh an there is {continue, Continue} now :)